# Join two tables into one without repeating id in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

I'm trying to show the informacion I have in the tables "caractersiticas" and "Control" without including "codigoMaterial" which is related to "codigo".

I have tried this:

```
SELECT *
FROM caracteristicas
JOIN control
  ON codigo = codigoMaterial
```

I get all the results from both table and I don't want it to show one entire column. What shoud I do?

Comment: Use explicit Column names in `SELECT` instead of `*`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SELECT *` means show all the columns. Otherwise, you'll need to specify the columns you do want to show. You can also alias your tables to make reading easier:

```
SELECT car.Field1, car.Field2, cont.FieldA, cont.FieldB
FROM caracteristicas car
JOIN control cont
  ON car.codigo = cont.codigoMaterial
```